# In rails, given an array of Point objects, how do I sum the point values for each player?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

We're using postgres for this project.

The goal is to get a hash which pairs each player with the sum of their point values.

I have an array of `Point` objects which looks something like this:

(**Note**: each hash here is actually a database object from `Points.where`. The array is actually an `ActiveRecord:Relation` instance)

```
[
    { value: 3, player_id: 55 },
    { value: 1, player_id: 21 },
    { value: 2, player_id: 55 },
    { value: 6, player_id: 23 },
    { value: 2, player_id: 78 },
    { value: 2, player_id: 55 },
    { value: 5, player_id: 80 },
    { value: 7, player_id: 21 },
    { value: 2, player_id: 23 },
    { value: 1, player_id: 78 },
    { value: 4, player_id: 80 }
]
```

The expected output of this would be something like this:

```
{
    55: 7,
    21: 8,
    23: 8,
    78: 3,
    80: 9
}
```

Where the key is the player_id, and the value is the sum of all of their point values.

One solution in ruby I came up with uses activerecord to sum the points for each ID in the set.

```
points = get_the_points()

point_map = {}
ids = points.pluck(:player_id)

player_ids.each do |id|
    points_for_id = points.where(player_id: id).pluck(:value)
    sum_of_points = points_for_id.sum

    point_map[id] = sum_of_points
end

return point_map
```

But I know this can be done with SQL, and I know it'll be faster.

Because I'm just dealing with one model, I don't have to use joins or anything, do I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain SQL we would want something like:

```
SELECT points.user_id, SUM(points.value) AS sum_value
FROM points
GROUP BY points.user_id;
```

Which groups the rows by `user_id` and fetches an aggregate of `points.value`.

```
 user_id | sum_value 
---------+-----------
      14 |        18
      25 |        19
      17 |        29
      12 |        14
       8 |         9
       1 |        16
      15 |        19
      10 |        37
      11 |        26
       4 |        43
```

To get the same query in Rails you would use:

```
Point.group(:user_id).sum(:value)
```

> Because I'm just dealing with one model, I don't have to use joins or anything, do I?

Not unless you want to do something like a high score list where you list the users name and score.

Comment: Thanks! That was a lot simpler than I was giving it credit for.

I appreciate the explanation, too.

Comment: Soo, let's say that the requirements changed suddenly, and now I _do_ need to get information about the user. Where could I find info on using a join here?

Comment: Ask a new question and include your models. I can't think of a single source which really answers that. You can look at the questions that deal with getting a count of the associated records as the approach is similiar.

Answer (score 2):

Try in one SQL query

```
Point.group(:player_id).sum(:value)
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using this solution.

Comment: My pleasure Sir ;)